# Django overriding default managers of contrib models

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app named `site_settings` in which `SiteSettings` model is defined. This model contains a foreign key to `django.contrib.sites.models.Site` model. Now I want to override default `objects` manager of `Site` model with new one I defined:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import SiteManager as _OrigSiteManager


class SiteManager(_OrigSiteManager):
    ...
```

I tried:

```
Site.add_to_class("objects", SiteManager())
```

But it didn't work. The problem is I am adding to class with already existing `objects` name. When adding with another name, it works as expected:

```
Site.add_to_class("my_objects", SiteManager())  # now Site.my_objects points to my custom manager
```

But I want to override existing `objects` manager with my custom manager. How can I do that?

Comment: you say But it didn't work. What happened? Exception? Or nothing changes?

Comment: No exception or any other error. It just doesn't work. Django, somehow ignores `Site.add_to_class("objects", SiteManager())`. After this statement, `Site.objects` persists to point to the its own existing manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine and use your own Site class everywhere:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

    class Site(Site):
        ...
        objects = SiteManager()
```

or you can use `contribute_to_class`:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

SiteManager().contribute_to_class(Site, 'objects')
```

or you can made monkey patch:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

Site.objects = SiteManager(model=Site)
```

If you need it only to change queryset in foreignkey to Site, you can use `limit_choices_to`:

```
foreignkey(Site, limit_choices_to=Q(your query to limit sites queryset))
```

Comment: what is `Models` here? I also can't redefine `Site`, because it is already defined under `django.contrib.sites.model`

Comment: Thanks for the solutions suggested, but none of them is suitable: 1. This'd be good solution when starting project from scratch, but alread django's `Site` model is used everywhere.  2. This doesn't work. It is not much different from `Site.add_to_class("objects", SiteManager())`, so none of them works (they fail to override existing manager). 3. Same with second point, it is not working. 4. `limit_choices_to` only affect `ModelForm` and I don't need this.

Comment: already django's Site model is used everywhere. And what is difficult to change it everythere? find replace?

Comment: find and replace is not a problem. But many existing models contain foreign key to django's `Site` model. It is not easy to update those. But anyway this is not in scope of my question. I only want to achieve changing django's default `Site.objects`

Comment: please define once more time: Class._default_manager or Class.objects they are two different DataManagers.

Comment: I just want to achieve to point to my own custom manager (that I defined by inheriting `_OrigSiteManager`), when I type `Site.objects`

Comment: in python manage.py shell: from django.contrib.sites.models import Site, SiteManager
>>>Site.objects
<django.contrib.sites.models.SiteManager object at 0x000001F6EDD7F3D0>
>>>Site.objects.name
'objects'
>>>Site.objects = SiteManager() >>> vars(Site.objects).update(name='something', model = Site)
>>>Site.objects.__dict__
{'_constructor_args': ((), {}), 'creation_counter': 105, 'model': None, 'name': 'something', '_db': None, '_hints': {}}
>>>Site.objects
<django.contrib.sites.models.SiteManager object at 0x000001F6F7390FA0>
>>>Site.objects.all()
FEHLER: »django_site« existiert nicht.

Comment: can you please add screenshot or add this to your answer as code snippet? It's not understandable..

Comment: I mean: try to change objects in manage.py shell. If it works, it works everywhere. In my django 4.1 it works if i set Site.objects = MyManager

Comment: `vars(Site.objects).update(name='something', model = Site)` this seems like a hack, but works

Comment: you can add this code as a separate answer and I am happy to accept it. For your reference, I just discovered why `add_to_class` (or `contribute_to_class`) doesn't work. Look at this [if statement](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/db/models/options.py#L397) in django source code. It prevents registering multiple managers with the same name.